# Как правильно использовать XmlSerializer.deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Как десириализовать объект `XmlDocument` через класс `XmlSerializer` используя метод `deserialize()`? Сейчас я сохраняю `XmlDocument` во временный файл, и загружаю этот файл в `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` - метод (`Stream`). Но мне кажется это костыль... Как правильно будет?

Answer (score 6):

Не-не-не, всё не так.

XML-сериализация используется для того, чтобы объект *произвольного* типа представить в виде XML-документа и записать его в текстовом виде на диск. Для записи/чтения самого XML сериализация как бы и не нужна.

Для того, чтобы прочитать XML, сохранённый в текстовый файл, пользуйтесь [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx). А для того, чтобы сохранить `XmlDocument` в файл, [`XmlDocument.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx).

---

Если у вас *уже* есть строка, не нужно сохранять её в файл, оберните её в `MemoryStream` и отдайте десериализатору.

---

Короче, вот вам пример со всеми возможными вариантами сериализации и десериализации:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SerializtionFromXmlDocumentTest
{
    [Serializable]
    public class StaffEntry
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var entries = new[]
                {
                    new StaffEntry() { Name = "Fry" },
                    new StaffEntry() { Name = "Leela" }
                };

            var doc = SerializeToXmlDocument(entries);
            var restoredEntries = DeserializeFromXmlDocument(doc).ToList();

            var stringDoc = SerializeToString(entries);
            var restoredEntries2 = DeserializeFromString(stringDoc).ToList();
        }

        static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument(IEnumerable<StaffEntry> entries)
        {
            XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StaffEntry));

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("StaffEntries"));
            ((XmlElement)root).SetAttribute(
                    "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            ((XmlElement)root).SetAttribute(
                    "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

            var navigator = root.CreateNavigator();
            foreach (var staffEntry in entries)
            {
                using (var writer = navigator.AppendChild())
                {
                    writer.WriteWhitespace("");
                    seri.Serialize(writer, staffEntry);
                }
            }

            return doc;
        }

        static IEnumerable<StaffEntry> DeserializeFromXmlDocument(XmlDocument doc)
        {
            XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StaffEntry));

            using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                reader.ReadStartElement();
                while (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    StaffEntry entry = (StaffEntry)seri.Deserialize(reader);
                    yield return entry;
                }
            }
        }

        static string SerializeToString(IEnumerable<StaffEntry> entries)
        {
            XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StaffEntry));
            var prefix = "<StaffEntries>";
            var postfix = "</StaffEntries>";
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                output.Append("    ");
                var writer = XmlWriter.Create(
                               output,
                               new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
                seri.Serialize(writer, entry, ns);
                output.AppendLine();
            }

            return prefix + Environment.NewLine + output + postfix;
        }

        static IEnumerable<StaffEntry> DeserializeFromString(string stringDoc)
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(stringDoc);
            return DeserializeFromXmlDocument(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD, нееее! не сериализация, а десериализация. У меня есть xml файл, в его структуре есть список из тегов StaffEntry, то есть <StaffEntry>...<StaffEntry/><StaffEntry>...<StaffEntry/>...
мне нужно из этого файла передать данные (StaffEntry) веб-сервису, в прокси-классе есть тип только одного StaffEntry. вот я их подряд считываю, записываю в отдельный файл и десириализую. Мои StaffEntry не отсортированны и по этому другой класс десериализации использовать не могу.

Comment: @YGOR-CHAMIN: Ну так натравите XmlReader на документ, и десериализуйте последовательно `StaffEntry` из него.

Comment: @YGOR-CHAMIN: Дополнил ответ.