# Получение значений из xml в C#

Tags: c#, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Как получить значение first_name и last_name в виде текста из этого XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response list="true">
 <user>
  <id>210700286</id>
  <first_name>Lindsey</first_name>
  <last_name>Stirling</last_name>
  <bdate>21.9.1986</bdate>
 </user>
</response>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/246609/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-xmlserializer-deserialize

Comment: Лично я предпочитаю `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("response/user/first_name").InnerText`

Comment: Лично я бы описал бы класс user и десериализовал бы целиком, а не по одному полю тащил бы: сегодня одно, завтра другое... зачем, если можно сразу целиком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");
var first_name = doc.GetElementsByTagName("first_name")[0].InnerText;
var last_name = doc.GetElementsByTagName("last_name")[0].InnerText;
```